# Best practices to migrate old portal to new portal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, migration, asp.net-mvc-views

I have new requirements for a ASP.Net MVC system that is up and running but unfortunetly it is not well designed (e.g. database is accessed directly from controllers and from within the views sometimes).

So i proposed a new domain-driven architecture to the system and we will start migrating from the old system to the new architecture by modules and functions.

But i am facing a problem, i need to share the different layouts between the two systems, any ideas on how to do this?

Generally,any best practices for scenarios like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there just too many layouts or too complex layouts to simply copy them to the new system?

Comment: I tried to do so, but unfortunately there is a database code written in these layout! to access the rules and build the menus. plus there are multiple layouts!

Answer (score 0):

I've previously migrated a site away from using `ViewBag` to use strongly-typed views. This included a strongly-typed _layout page.

I had to create the "correct" _layout page from a copy of the original and clean it up. Then I migrated one controller/view at a time until I was able to remove the old views.